# Making Word template from dynamics crm and change date format merge field XML mapping pane

Tags: ms-word, dynamics-crm, cpu-word

I have a date field (via developer tab and XML Mapping Pane tab). It looks like DD-MM-YYYY ("14-09-2021"). I would like the field to be "14 September 2021" when it comes through into word.

It is a date-picker content control. I try to change the date format from the Properties dialog:

[image]

But the format keeps staying 14-10-2021.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to create a new "formatted date" field, and use a free tool such as Kaskela Workflow Elements to convert the original format into the one you use in your template. Once you import the Kaskela solution, then you get a new workflow step that lets you convert the date format into anything you want, for example: [image]